# Regular expression multiple search and replace?

Tags: regex, powergrep

I need a single regex to replace multiple words: 111, 222, 333, in text like this with 444, 555, 666 (case insensitive):

```
randomtext111randomtext
randomtext222
randomtext
333randomtext
randomtext
```

To replace with words 444, 555, 666
to have this result:

```
randomtext444randomtext
randomtext555
randomtext
666randomtext
randomtext
```

I managed to replace when every word is in single line, with this:

```
(111)
(222)
(333)
```

replace with

```
444
555
666
```

but it doesnt work in above example.

(I use powergrep)

Comment: What's wrong with replacing `STRING` with `WORD`?

Comment: I edited the question to make it clear.

Comment: How do you get the job done for the simpler case with a single regex?